# Moving EntityFramework database to Azure, MigrationHistory table is lost

Tags: entity-framework, azure

I'm in the process of migrating our on-premises hosted ASP.NET application into the cloud and I'm running into an issue with the migration of my database.

We're using EF5 for database interaction and we've enabled the code first migrations in order to deal with database changes. However, whenever I generate a BACPAC file the __MigrationHistory table is ignored and when I use the SSIS tool to migrate data between my local and Azure database the values in the identity columns are changed regardless of whether I select 'enable identity insert', messing up my entire database.

What am I doing wrong here? I've tried various routes and none seem to have the desired effect.

Thanks,
Patrick

Comment: I have not used Sql Azure too much so I may be wrong but instead of moving all the schema why not to use migrations to create the database in the Sql Azure and migrate only data?

Comment: That was my first solution, but that messes up all columns that use an identity value. It pretty much resets all the Ids to start at 1 again which messes up all the relationships between various tables.

Comment: You may just try disabling identities on columns for migrating the data (not sure if this would really work for you though)

Comment: I managed to migrate my database by ditching a subset of the data  which was being kept for administrative reasons, like which user made certain edits and wrote a script for fixing the broken Ids in the various tables. It wasn't pretty, especially since this problems will most likely show its ugly head again when restoring a backup.

Comment: Glad you were able to solve it!